ionic 7 keyboard does not let see input fields
so the fields that are below the keyboard stays below. even if I hide the keyboard and then tap on the lower area fields the keyboard will cover those and make it impossible to enter data.
Attaching this video
keyboard issue on input fields
my package.json is
{
  "name": "baniya",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Moblize.it LLC",
  "homepage": "https://baniya.app",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor-community/apple-sign-in": "^5.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.0.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/browser": "^5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.0.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "5.0.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.2",
    "@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth": "^3.3.2",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "chartjs-gauge": "^0.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "swiper": "^9.3.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/assets": "^2.0.4",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "Baniya App by Moblize.it LLC"
}


have you tried this solution? https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/118#issuecomment-1049300493

Add space below the ion-content tag, you can choose any margin-bottom value you prefer, such as margin-bottom: 100px;. I found this approach to be the simplest.
